# How can I specify the image facebook will show when using a redirect?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We are building a mobile app and are sharing a user's ranking. To do so, we have a URL set up that simply returns og- tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{{ env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID') }}" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="{{ $url }}" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="{{ $title }}" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="{{ $content }}" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="{{ $image }}" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url={{ $url }}" />
        <title>Redirecting...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The only problem is it is ignoring the meta data on this view in favor of the meta data from the redirect URL. For example, we can set a description and image here, but if the redirect URL goes to google, then it will grab google's description and image.

If we disable the `og:url` and `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url={{ $url }}" />` tags, then it displays the proper content, but the user won't be redirected properly.

Can I force it to use the metadata from this page (such as the image, description, etc.) while still presenting the redirect URL?

Comment: You need to set `og:url` to the URL of _this_ document, that contains those meta tags ...

Comment: How will Facebook treat that differently than not including a URL at all? What happens in that case?

Comment: If there is no indication that it should look for the meta data under a different location, then it won't ...

Comment: So I can show the image OR I can redirect the user. Is there a way to do both?

Comment: Server-side redirect with an exception for the Facebook scraper, or client-side JavaScript ...